# Swift Convert Int[] to Int variable

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, type-conversion

Working with Swift 3 I got an Int array created from number and Reversed

```
var rev:String = String(number)
var pro:String = String(rev.characters.reversed())

var myArr = rev.characters.flatMap{Int(String($0))}
myArr = myArr.sorted { $1 < $0 }
```

Now i want to

```
var myResult = all numbers from array in one variable
```

Let say

```
myArr = [1,2,3,4]
// And i want to myResult = 1234
```

Or if there's any other way to reverse just a number, I mean normal Integer variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can try like this way

```
let myArr = [1,2,3,4]

let myResult = myArr.map(String.init).joined()
```

If you want myResult as `Int` then

```
let myResult = myArr.map(String.init).joined()
if let intResult = Int(myResult) {
    print(intResult)
}
```

Comment: Keep attention on Int range. Handle optional value, do not force unwrap.

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz If you check the question/answer number is made from Int array so it will not crash if you convert the merge string number.

Comment: @NiravD it will crash if the value created is too large to be an integer. For instance, `let myArr = [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]`

Comment: @ConnorNeville Edit answer now it will not crash.

Comment: @ConnorNeville yeah, I thought about example like this

Answer (score 5):

Combining the array of decimal digits to a number can be done with
simple integer arithmetic:

```
let digits = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let result = digits.reduce(0, { $0 * 10 + $1 })
print(result) // 1234
```

> Or if there's any other way to reverse just a number, I mean normal Integer variable?

You don't need an array or a string conversion for that purpose:

```
func reverse(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    var n = n // A mutable copy of the given number
    while n > 0 {
        // Append last digit of `n` to `result`:
        result = 10 * result + n % 10  
        // Remove last digit from `n`:
        n /= 10
    }
    return result
}

print(reverse(12345)) // 54321
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map your numbers to Strings, then concatenate them and convert the String to an Int.

```
if let result = Int(myArray.map{String($0)}.joined()) {
    //your number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want here. If you just want to reverse an Int then probably Martin R's solution is the best option (with simple arithmetic).

Now, if you want to sort the number and then convert it into an Int I'd recommend something like this:

```
let number = 1432
let string = String(String(number).characters.sorted(by: >))

let integerValue = Int(string) // Returns 4321
```

This will return an optional Int.